# How do I predict values for the future instead of a known column?

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, predict

I'm trying to predict the future values in a data.frame in R but I keep getting all of the same numbers as the column that I'm predicting on. Here is the code-

```
df=read.csv(file="D://Users/me/Documents/df.csv", header=FALSE, row.names=NULL)

df <- data.frame(t(df))

df <- df[-c(21),]

fit <- lm(X1~., data=df)
predict(fit)
```

The values being predicted are the following-

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 
4   8  13  16  19  24  26  31  34  37  40  42  46  50  56  58  59  64  72  80
```

These numbers turn out to be the exact same numbers as the ones in column X1. I'm trying to predict the next column given all columns before (including X1) along with probabilities. When I do `plogis(predict(fit))` I get the following.

```
   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10 
0.9820138 0.9996646 0.9999977 0.9999999 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 
  V11       V12       V13       V14       V15       V16       V17       V18       V19       V20 
1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

So, as you can see, it looks like it is somewhat making a prediction, but the probabilities are so high that the numbers match up perfectly with the column.

How do I predict the next column? And then how do I predict the column after that? etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing there is:

load your data from csv file

```
df=read.csv(file="D://Users/me/Documents/df.csv", header=FALSE, row.names=NULL)
```

transpose what you've loaded

```
df <- data.frame(t(df))
```

remove the row number 21

```
df <- df[-c(21),]
```

fit a linear regression model on the previous dataframe where your DV is X1 and using all the remaining variables as predictors

```
fit <- lm(X1~., data=df)
```

call the function predict over your model

```
predict(fit)
```

In R, when you do the last, you are telling R to predict the data points that were used to fit your original model. This is usually a way to validate the results in your training. If you wanted to predict new values (a new dataset) then you have to specify the dataset with the new data you want to predict

```
predict(fit, newdata = myNewDF)
```

This myNewDF should be a dataframe containing all your variables except from that X1 that you are trying to predict.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I have a problem now though. The data that I have is big; not too big but over 15,000 columns. I just want to predict the next 2 columns and not create an invisible data.frame. Is there a way to do that? I wan't efficiency over anything so that's why I only want to predict 2, maybe up to 10, columns.

Comment: Also, let me ask you this. When I first ran it I needed to create `myNewDF`, so I just did `myNewDF <- data.frame`. After I did that I tried your answer (`predict(fit, newdata = myNewDF` and it gave me this error- `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'`. How do I fix this and can you put it in the answer too as well?

Comment: Regarding your first question, I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to predict. Remember that when making a model you need the same data structure for predicting and training the model, for example if you try to make a model to predict the price of a house based on surface, city, beedrom_number and bathroom_number you will train the model with these parameters, and when making predictions of new houses you will need all your predictors and the same categories (for example you cannot have a new city). I need to know more about your data in order to give you a better answer.

Comment: `dim(df)` is `[1] 20 15964`. I don't have any column names (`X1, X2... Xn`) and I'm only trying to predict 2 to 10 columns, maybe even just one. I don't want to create another table consisting of approx 16k columns again because most of that data is useless. I just have a set of 20 numbers (1 through 80) and I'm trying to predict the next 20 numbers based on historical data. I don't have a test set, maybe I should split `df` into training and test, but I don't even think I know how to test that. That's partially why I asked.

Comment: Regarding your second question, the error you are getting is related to the parenthesis. You should do `predit(fit, newdata= myNewDF)` Also when creating the data frame you have to put some data inside `myNewDF = data.frame(mypredictorcolumns)` for example in the previous example `myNewDF = data.frame(surface, city, beedrom_number and bathroom_number)`

Comment: I did this- `myNewDF <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=20, ncol=length(df)))`. Sorry to further complicate things but I don't only want predicted values, I want the probability of those values as well >.<

Comment: If you are using lm you are fitting a regression model. You won't have probabilities, instead of that you can have the range of values to a given confidence level, for example, your prediction will be between 1.2 and 1.8 at a 95% confidence level. For doing that you have to code `predict(fit, newdata = myNewDF, inteval = "confidence", level = 0.95)`

Comment: A full example of the process here

`data("quakes");
train = quakes[1:900,];
test = quakes[901:1000, c("depth","stations")];
fit = with(train,lm(mag~depth + stations));
predict(fit, newdata=test, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95);`

Comment: Yup you lost me. Sorry -.-

Comment: With the last comment? I was trying to show you an example of the whole process with a dataset we can both use, the data "quakes" comes by default in R. What I did is, (1) load the data, (2) create a train for fitting, (3) create as test for validating with my predictors as columns, (4) fit a model where I try to predict mag using depth and stations as predictors, (5) predict the model on the newdata (test data) and plot the confidence intervals. Remember that is regression problems, unlike classification problems, there are not probabilities, only confidence margins.

Comment: Yes, I want the confidence margins but I'm still stuck and getting errors when I'm just trying to predict 1 or 2 columns with the `newdata` arg.

Comment: can I use `plogis(predict(fit, newdata=predictions, na.rm=TRUE))` for the confidence?

Comment: It won't work, if you want the confidence intervals you have to pass the argument `interval = "confidence"` inside the predict. The plogis is the inverse logit function, it won't yield any meaningful result in a linear regression prediction.

Comment: I want to mark this as an answer because everything says that this is right but I keep getting errors.

Comment: I think the errors come from the dataset you are using the way you are using it, any chance I can take a look?

Comment: Yea, how can I send it to you? Just screencap it?

Comment: Could you upload it in some service such as dropbox or mega and send me the link? (only if is not sensitive data and is something that can be publicity shared)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzGPJ4-xoC1oUURaQXVrSFVJUkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Following your code. The first error I see is in the loading `df=read.csv(file="D://Users/me/Documents/df.csv", header=FALSE, row.names=NULL);
df <- data.frame(t(df))` When doing that you are including the column and row names inside the dataframe df, if you explore X1 with `df$X1` you will see what I am talking about. By the way, what is the purpose of this exercise? because this data looks like some sort of time series data, am I right?

Comment: Yes it is time series data. The problem you mentioned is not a problem, I just did `write.csv(file=etc.)` and included the headers and row names. The real data I'm loading doesn't have that. It is a time series though. I just want predicted values from the series and hopefully confidence levels in the values.

Comment: I understand now. In R time series data has its own way. First you have to create a time series object. Check this website http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html and this other one https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1 for more information about time series prediction using ARIMA and using ARIMA with regressors `Arima(myDV, xreg=myPredictors,
          order=c(2,0,0))` where you can play with different orders for the Arima and including different predictors. Hope this helps